# Crawling of relative URL's with Scrapy [Python]

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm SEO specialist, not really into coding.. But want to try to create a broken links checker in Python with Scrapy module, which will crawl my website and will show me all internal links with 404 code..

So far I have managed to write this code:

```py
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from crawler.items import Broken


    class Spider(CrawlSpider):
        name = 'example'
        handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
        allowed_domains = ['www.example.com']

        start_urls = ['https://www.example.com']

        rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_info', follow=True)]
        def parse_info(self, response):
            report = [404]
            if response.status in report:
                Broken_URLs = Broken()
                #Broken_URLs['title']= response.xpath('/html/head/title').get()
                Broken_URLs['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
                Broken_URLs['status_code']= response.status
                Broken_URLs['url']= response.url
                Broken_URLs['anchor']= response.meta.get('link_text')


                return Broken_URLs
```

It's crawling well, as long as we have absolute url's in the site structure.

But there some cases when the crawler comes across with relative url's and end up with this kind of links:

Normally should be:

https://www.example.com/en/...

But it gives me:

https://www.example.com/en/en/... - double language folder, which end up with 404 code.

I'm trying to find a way to override this language duplication, with correct structure at the end.

Does somebody know the way how to fix it? Will much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy use `urllib.parse.urljoin` for working with relative urls.

You can fix it by adding custom function into `process_request` in `Rule` definition:

```py
def fix_urls():
    def process_request(request, response):
        return request.replace(url=request.url.replace("/en/en/", "/en/"))
    return process_request

class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example'
...
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), process_request=fix_urls(), callback='parse_info', follow=True)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But what I should do in case if I have a few language directories? Not only /en/en/, but also /es/es/, /fr/fr/ etc? Is there any way to add multiple replace rules?

Comment: You can add additional `replace` calls like this `request.url.replace("/en/en/", "/en/").replace("/es/es/", "/es/").replace("/fr/fr/", "/fr/")` etc.